# What is the use of HTTP Cache Manager and HTTP Cookie Manager for the Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

```
What is the use of HTTP Cache Manager and HTTP Cookie Manager
```

and how it performs if we enable/disable the options to clear them in each iteration?

Answer (score 6):

Both are to make load test more realistic.

- HTTP Cookie Manager - holds cookies which usually are being used for identifying user session including login information.
- HTTP Cache Manager - represents browser cache. Real browsers download different embedded stuff like images, styles, scripts, etc. during rendering web page but do it **only once** or based on what specific cache control headers tell.
- Clear above each iteration - if **enabled** new test cycle starts "clean" i.e. each virtual user will have to log in, fetch all the data, etc. so it'll look like a **new user** to the system under test. If **disabled** - it'll just be another test iteration for **the same** virtual user

So if your idea is to make your test more close to [real browser testing](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you need to use above test elements in combination with [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configuring [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to tell all the HTTP Samples to download embedded resources and use concurrent pool of 2-5 threads for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should read those 2 docs:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Answer (score -1):

Question?
To stimulate browser behavior more realistic do we have to enable "Use Cache-Control/Expires header when processing get request"? during Load Test.

I am asserting the response for get request. If is use this then is there any chance for me to get null response?

I was confused with the detail gathered?